# Complex For & If loop confusion, returning and accessing classes. Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, class, uiimageview, for-loop

I have a view which has a number of subviews. I need to find a particular UIImageView with a particular UIImage.

Here is the code I'm using to loop through:

```
BOOL fileExistsAtLocation;
for (id subview in drawGallery.subviews){
    if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIImageView class]]){
        // I need to detect the subview's image property to see if it matches.
    }
}
```

I've tried

```
if(subview.image == [UIImage imageNamed:image]){

}
```

But I'm getting told that image isn't part of the structure, which is understandable as all the subviews are essentially of UIView type. How do I target only the UIImageViews and then check their image property?

Regarding the 'tag' answer, the code I tried was:

```
BOOL fileIsAtLocation;
for (id subview in drawGallery.subviews){
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]){
        if ((UIView *)subview.tag){
            NSLog(@"FOUND");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[UIImage imageNamed:image] will return a new instance of that image so it will NEVER be equal.  I'd suggest tagging all of your subviews.  So when you create the image views, assign a unique tag (this could just be an auto incrementing number).  Then you can detect of interest based on the tag.

```
BOOL fileExistsAtLocation;
for (id subview in drawGallery.subviews){
    if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]){
        // I need to detect the subview's image property to see if it matches.
        if([(UIView *)subView tag] == uniqueIDAssignedToImage) {
            // You have found your view   
        }
    }
}
```

Also use isKindOfClass to check the class type.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, `UIImage` caches. But yeah, pointer equality is still not guaranteed.

Comment: I have this `for (id subview in drawGallery.subviews){ if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]){ NSLog(@"%d", (UIView *)subview.tag);` and it's giving me the same error - request for member tag is not of structure or union blah blah. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Totally, it was poorly phrased.  But you're right, you have no guarantee when the cache will flush/restore modifying the pointer.

Comment: Try `[(UIView *)subview tag]`

Comment: It's not letting me target any properties for any object. UIImageView, UIView OR NSObject.

Comment: Hrm... even when you try calling the accessor method for the property that I suggested above?  I just tested it in a sample app and it worked just fine.

Comment: The syntax for casting "subview" is `((UIView*)subview).tag`. However, the better approach is to simply change the type of "subview" to UIView.  E.g., `for (UIView* subview in drawGallery.subviews)`, then you don't need to cast anything.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use type conversion?

```
if(((UIImageView *)subview).image == [UIImage imageNamed:image]){

}
```

**UPDATE:**

- You can also try to change iteration logic:

  `for (UIView *subview in drawGallery.subviews) {`
- If you have to find a single view with tag, try

  `UIImageView *imageViewISearchFor = [drawGallery viewWithTag:uniqueIDAssignedToImage];`

Comment: It just says "request for member 'image' in something not a structure or union"

Comment: Because is must be `if(((UIImageView *)subview).image == [UIImage imageNamed:image]){` (additional braces around the conversion). But still, assign tags to subviews, and find them using `viewWithTag:`, it's fast.